# Unity 4.6+ Creating Text through a Script

Tags: c#, user-interface, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create text dynamically so that depending on the number of players, the UI changes. However as I've coded it at the moment, the objects are created and everything seems to work apart from the text is not visible on the screen or in scene view. The object is there, just not the text. Can anyone see the issue or know how to resolve this?

I'm using C# btw.

```
public class UserInterface : MonoBehaviour {


public Canvas UI;
public GameObject DamageCounter;
public Color[] colors = new Color[4];

private static List<GameObject> players; 
Text uiText;
RectTransform uiPos;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    players = PlayerManager.getPlayers ();
    float screenHalf = Screen.width / 2;
    float screenDiv = Screen.width / players.Count;
    Debug.Log ("ScreenDiv = " + screenDiv);


    for (int i = 1; i < players.Count + 1; i++) 
    {

        GameObject playerText = new GameObject("Text");
        playerText.layer = 5;
        uiPos = playerText.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
        uiText = playerText.AddComponent<Text>();
        playerText.transform.SetParent(UI.transform, false);
        uiPos.sizeDelta.Set(Screen.width, Screen.height);
        uiPos.anchoredPosition3D = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        uiPos.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(10, 10);
        uiPos.localScale = new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        uiPos.localPosition.Set(0, 0, 0);
        uiText.supportRichText = true;
        uiText.fontSize = 150;
        uiText.font = Resources.GetBuiltinResource(typeof(Font), "Arial.ttf") as Font;
        uiText.alignment = TextAnchor.MiddleCenter;
        uiText.horizontalOverflow = HorizontalWrapMode.Overflow;
        uiText.verticalOverflow = VerticalWrapMode.Overflow;
        uiText.color = colors[i - 1];
        uiText.text = "WORK";
        Debug.Log ("HERE:" + (i * screenDiv - screenHalf));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check if the text is shown in the text component within the editor? As soon as you hit play, "WORK" should appear there.
Also, is there any error in the console?

Comment: Yes, the text is shown correctly in the inspector and there are no errors in the console.

Comment: Weird. Did you set the colors from the "colors" array with alpha of 1f?

Comment: Omg, thank you so much. I knew it was something simple, as I couldn't see any issues. Thank you so much for this, I've been hitting my head against a brick wall for hours (embarrassingly so, it now seems).

Comment: This kind of things happen to everyone! Haha 
Good luck with your game!